# What is the integral of this function from $0$ to $1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Here is the integral:

$$\int _0^1\left(\frac{1-x^x}{x^{1/x}}\right)^{\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}\mathrm dx$$

The function looks like this:

[image: The function]

I tried to use WolframAlpha, but I only found an approximated result, which was $0.724961$.

I tried to do it myself, but I didn't know how to start.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Is there any reason why you would expect this to have a nice answer?

Comment: I tried an inverse symbolic calculator lookup but with those few digits there are too many results.

Comment: i don't think there is a nice result